# How to edit a last bot send

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

I need to edit the last message from bot. But I don't know how get ID of last sended messade.
This code

```
bot.hears('hi', async (ctx) =>{
  try{
    await ctx.reply('hello')
    ctx.editMessageText(ctx.from.id, ctx.from.message.id, "second text")
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e)
  }
})
```

give me this result:

```
TypeError: Telegraf: "editMessageText" isn't available for "message"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID is included in the return value of `ctx.reply`.

You can then use it like this:

```
const { message_id } = await ctx.reply('hello');

// use message_id
```

Here's an example:

```
const { message_id } = await ctx.reply('hello');
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000);
await ctx.telegram.editMessageText(ctx.chat.id, message_id, 0, 'new text');
```